# Package array error

Tags: packages, arrays

I'm trying to write the following on my latex

```
$$(T_n f)(z)=n^{2k-1} \sum_{\begin{array}\ a\geq 1,ad=n \\ 0\leq b<d\end{array}} d^{-2k} f\left(\frac{az+b}{d}\right)$$
```

But it ends up with error:

```
! Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (\ ): `c'
```

used.

The header I used:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart} 
\usepackage{fullpage} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows, decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Don't use `$$...$$`, use `\[ ... \]` instead. But the error is `\begin{array}...\end{array}`. `\begin{array}{c}...\end{array}` is probably what you need, i.e. a `column` specifier. `array` is like a `tabular`

Comment: just for information ... `amsart` incorporates `amsthm` and loads `amsmath`, so it's not necessary to specify those for inclusion.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thanks for welcoming ^_^. I use the double dolars because I want it on the next line.

Comment: @barbarabeeton OK noted. So I just erase the amsmath and amsthm right? Thanks :)

Comment: @ChenMLing: `\[...\]` does the same. `$$...$$` is deprecated syntax

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Oh I see... I just started learning latex so my knowledge is still very limited.

Comment: @ChenMLing -- yes, that's all you need to do.  (actually, it won't hurt if you don't remove them, but it could be misleading for someone else if you try to attach an option to one of them at the `\usepackage` level -- that won't work since they've already been included.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array` takes a mandatory argument. It would probably be much easier for you to write `\sum_{\substack{a\geq1, ad=n \\ 0\leq b<d}}`

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart} 
\usepackage{fullpage} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows, decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
(T_n f)(z)=n^{2k-1} \sum_{\substack{ a\geq 1,ad=n \\ 0\leq b<d }} 
d^{-2k} f\left(\frac{az+b}{d}\right)
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note how `\substack` makes the subscript in a smaller font, whereas `array` does not.

BTW: please always post full minimal examples including preamble and body that others can just copy'n'paste and use immediately without having to add anything. That makes others much more inclined to help.

Comment: Oh yeah. That works! Thanks very much. Sorry that I didn't post full minimal examples, I'm new here and just learn how to post nicely. :) Thanks again...

Comment: @ChenMLing also remember to make the example minimal, for example here, none of the used packages are relevant, as `amsart` already loads `amsmath` and the others are not related to the issue.